# Trust badges html css and script

Tags: html, css, badge

I am trying to do custom badges on my store. I want to have 4 objects with info like "fast shipping". When clicking on one of them, a small descriptive text will show just underneath.

Now, my problem is that I can't find a way to set the `<p>` to width 100% only when active, without putting it 100% all the time (which will make it all look bad when not pressed)

Can someone give me tips on how to do this? <3 I am out of ideas hahah

Here is my code, thanks!

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-2");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion-2 {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.164);
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: italic;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.active,
.accordion-2:hover {
  background-color: rgb(212, 245, 255);
}

.accordion-2-guld:hover {
  background-color: rgb(236, 185, 45);
}

.accordion-2:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.panel:after {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion-2">Gratis frakt</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Gratis | Postnord Hemleverans 3-5 dagar.<br><br>49kr | Skickas samma dag eller dagen efter. 1-2 arbetsdagar.<br><br>57kr | Utlämningsställe</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion-2">Enkel retur</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Byta storlek eller färg? Inga problem! <br><br> Du står för frakten till oss och vi skickar gratis tillbaka nya produkter!</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion-2">Fin paketbox</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Varje smycke kommer fint paketerad i våra fina askar och läderpåsar. De kommer i vit eller svart och olika storlekar. Vi ser till att paketet passar just din beställning  Har du ett speciellt önskemål är det bara att lägga en liten kommentar vi utcheckning,
    så löser vi det!</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion-2">Betala efter 30 dagar med Klarna</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Vi erbjuder Klarna betalning, Swish &amp; Kortbetlaning.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Add an 'active' class on click which styles as needed. Remove the class when you click elsewhere or after timeout or whatever trigger you prefer.

Comment: You use `float: left` on `button` and the `panel` which contain description is stay aside the button that is floating left. If you want the description to stay at the bottom then you have to wrap button and panel with elements to float left and display as 2 columns.

Comment: Thank you!! @vee and Roddy of the Frozen Peas! I was actually very happily surprised that I got replies! 
Now, I'm not too confident in script and I don't know if this will work with the code... I am frankly a bit unsure about the css as well, do you have any code suggestions with examples? It would be really appreciated! I feel a little stuck...

Thank you!! 

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Thank you!! Would it be possible to show how to do that in code? I really got stuck on this one, you would save my day! 

Thank you!! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 columns and description is under the button inside each column.

Use CSS grid.

Wrap your `button` and `.panel` into a `.column`. Use CSS grid to display 2 columns at `40%` each.
Remove `float: left` from your `button` and set `width: 100%` to your button.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-2");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion-columns::after {
    clear: both;
    content: '';
}
.accordion-columns {
    align-items: stretch;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 49%);
    justify-items: stretch;
}

.accordion-2 {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.164);
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: italic;
    transition: 0.2s;
    width: 100%;
}

.active,
.accordion-2:hover {
    background-color: rgb(212, 245, 255);
}

.accordion-2-guld:hover {
    background-color: rgb(236, 185, 45);
}

.accordion-2:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.panel:after {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion-columns">
    <div class="column">
        <button class="accordion-2">Gratis frakt</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>Gratis | Postnord Hemleverans 3-5 dagar.<br><br>49kr | Skickas samma dag eller dagen efter. 1-2 arbetsdagar.<br><br>57kr | Utlämningsställe</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <button class="accordion-2">Enkel retur</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>Byta storlek eller färg? Inga problem! <br><br> Du står för frakten till oss och vi skickar gratis tillbaka nya produkter!</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <button class="accordion-2">Fin paketbox</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>Varje smycke kommer fint paketerad i våra fina askar och läderpåsar. De kommer i vit eller svart och olika storlekar. Vi ser till att paketet passar just din beställning  Har du ett speciellt önskemål är det bara att lägga en liten kommentar vi utcheckning,
                så löser vi det!</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <button class="accordion-2">Betala efter 30 dagar med Klarna</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>Vi erbjuder Klarna betalning, Swish &amp; Kortbetlaning.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you will have 2 columns with description under the button inside each column.
See it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t3f8Lz7h/).

---

To have 2 columns but when active, display `.panel` in full width.

Use the same CSS grid as above but add `.active` class to `.column` in JS.  Modify `.accordion-columns .column.active` CSS to start and column 1 and end at the end.
Modify your CSS to display `+` and `-` correctly.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-2");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.closest('.column').classList.toggle('active');
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion-columns::after {
    clear: both;
    content: '';
}
.accordion-columns {
    align-items: stretch;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: [first] 49% [second] 49% [end];
    justify-items: stretch;
}
.accordion-columns .column.active {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: end;
}

.accordion-2 {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.164);
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: italic;
    transition: 0.2s;
    width: 100%;
}


.accordion-2:hover {
    background-color: rgb(212, 245, 255);
}

.accordion-2-guld:hover {
    background-color: rgb(236, 185, 45);
}

.accordion-2:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.accordion-2.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.panel:after {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion-columns">
    <div class="column">
        <button class="accordion-2">Gratis frakt</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>Gratis | Postnord Hemleverans 3-5 dagar.<br><br>49kr | Skickas samma dag eller dagen efter. 1-2 arbetsdagar.<br><br>57kr | Utlämningsställe</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <button class="accordion-2">Enkel retur</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>Byta storlek eller färg? Inga problem! <br><br> Du står för frakten till oss och vi skickar gratis tillbaka nya produkter!</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <button class="accordion-2">Fin paketbox</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>Varje smycke kommer fint paketerad i våra fina askar och läderpåsar. De kommer i vit eller svart och olika storlekar. Vi ser till att paketet passar just din beställning  Har du ett speciellt önskemål är det bara att lägga en liten kommentar vi utcheckning,
                så löser vi det!</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <button class="accordion-2">Betala efter 30 dagar med Klarna</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>Vi erbjuder Klarna betalning, Swish &amp; Kortbetlaning.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t3f8Lz7h/1/).